# Trouble with increment operator

Tags: c, operators

This is the exemplar code that I encountered in entry level Computer Programming course:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     int l = 20, m = 10;
     int z;
     z= l++ || m++;
     printf("z = %d l = %d m = %d\n", z, l, m);
 }
```

The code prints l=21, m=10 and z=1
values of l and z are what was expected by me, but value of m is troubling me. Shouldn't it be 11 as m++ is present in code.

Comment: If you know that `z = 1` is correct then you can figure out why   `m++` was never executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `m++` would only be executed if `l++ == 0`. Since `l++` evaluates to `20` then `m++` is never executed. If `l` was `0` initially then `m++` would be executed.

Comment: I think it would be good to explain a bit about short circuit evaluation, to better understand why.

Answer (score 3):

```
z= l++ || m++;
```

In your expression, `l` first assign value and after incremented one.

In **Logical or (||) operation**, If the **left operand is non-zero**, then right operand is **not evaluated** and the result is true. That's why `l` become `21` and m not evaluated and it's value is `10`.

C standard(**N1256 : 6.5.14-paragraph 4**) say's:

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; **there is a sequence point after the
>   evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares unequal
>   to 0, the second operand is not evaluated**.

Comment: You mean that it's evaluated first, right?

Comment: @Iharob In logical AND operation, first check left operand value, If it's true then not check right operand value.

Comment: @KeineLust Thank you for suggesting me.

Comment: Nitpick: Whether the increment is done before the assignment or afterwards is unspecified. All the post-increment operator guarantees is that the value before the increment is yielded and the inrement is completed at the next sequence point. Oh, and C99 is **not** standard, it has been canceled with the release of C11 6 years ago. It does not make a difference here, but you should update your documentation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is called short circuit evaluation.

Your line here:

```
 z= l++ || m++;
```

Says, *Check the value of l (increment while checking it). If l is non-0, set z to 1. If l is 0, check the value of m (increment while checking it). if m is non-0, set z to 1. Otherwise set z to 0.*

Essentially, when the first of the two checks (`l++`) already evaluates true, there is no need for the system to check the second condition, so it doesn't, and thus also fails to increment m.